# How string number convert to integer number?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string a = "1234"; //How this string convert in integer number

   system("pause");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

string a = "1234";
How this convert in integer

Comment: Read about [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Answer (score 2):

If you have C++11 and onwards, use

```
int n = std::stoi(a);
```

(Pre C++11, you could use `std::strtol;`)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `atoi`, instead use [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Good point; do you mind if I amend?

Comment: using stoi for a short range of number but if you have a lengthy number it fails to perform the conversion

Answer (score 2):

You can use [std::stoi()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert a `std::string` to an `int`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
   std::string a = "1234"; //How this string convert in integer number
   int b = std::stoi(a);
   system("pause");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use std::stoi:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string s = "123";
int number= std::stoi(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use boosts lexical cast

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

std::string str_num = "12345";
int value = 0;
try
{
    value = boost::lexical_cast<int>(str_num);
}
catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast &)
{
    // error with conversion - calling code will deal with
}
```

This way you can easily modify the code to deal with float or double if your string contains those types of numeric value also

Comment: This approach is indeed superior when trying back-and-forth parsing with templates.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ Standard has a special function

```
int stoi(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try this

```
string a = "28787" ;
int myNumber;
istringstream ( a) >> myNumber;
```

See or you can search for stoi function and see how it can be used. Probably It can work but never try because I dont have the compiler of c++